# reflect the value of enum to be a value of a class

Tags: dart

I need to do this Scenario, using enums and classes:

-> make x trigger the value of MaterialWidgets class;

-> String x= "radio";

-> print(MaterialWidgetsEnum.x);

-> the print supposed to be "radio"

```
enum MaterialWidgetsEnum{radio,button,navigator}
class MaterialWidgets{
 static String radio="radio";
  static String button="button";
  static String navigator="navigator";
}
int main()
{
  MaterialWidgetsEnum e = MaterialWidgetsEnum.radio;
  String x='radio';
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use it like that

```
MaterialWidgetsEnum.radio.toString().split('.')[1]
```

Edit:
if you want to return a specific value depends on enum object use a switch to return the value

```
String fromEnum(MaterialWidgetsEnum myEnum){
  switch(myEnum){
    case MaterialWidgetsEnum.redio:
      return 'radio';
    case MaterialWidgetsEnum.button:
      return 'button';
    case MaterialWidgetsEnum.navigation:
      return 'navigation';
    default:
      return 'default';
  }
}
```

Comment: i wanted to create just a refection using code not handling a string value

Comment: @winter I have edited my answer with a new one